# setDrawerLockMode is not working as expected

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to Android. I made an android app containing a navigation drawer. But, i need to customize this a little. When I click on a item in my drawer, I need to prevent this from closing. But, when I click on toggle button it must be closed.

So, I used `mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);` inside `onCreate()` in `MainActivity`. But, It didn't change anything.

So, i added this code inside `onDrawerClosed` and `onDrawerOpened`.

Here is my code.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle(); //*

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#473641"))); // change the color of header

        mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_menu, R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name)
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
            }
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                //invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_deals);
    }
```

This code also didn't work as expected. After I click on a item in list drawer suddenly closes and opens. But, what I need is keep opening the drawer until I click on toggle button.

Thanks :)

Comment: There's a method in your `NavigationDrawerFragment` that handles the list item clicks. In that method, there should be a call to `DrawerLayout#closeDrawer()`. If you don't want the drawer to close there, don't call that method. It's unclear if you actually want to lock the drawer open. Locking means the user can't open/close the drawer directly, but `openDrawer()` and `closeDrawer()` will still work. If locking isn't what you actually want, then remove the `setDrawerLockMode()` calls. If it is what you want, then you'll have to change those calls somewhat.

Comment: When I select an item from the drawer, it suddenly closing. I need to prevent that. but, after done selecting I need to close the drawer by clicking on toggle button. :)

Comment: Added  mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView); inside onItemClick and its working. Thanks. :)